# Eclipse adding the project overrides maven dependency

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies

I have a maven project that uses other small projects. And I added them to master's pom file.
So my Eclipse project properties looks like following:

```
>Master project
  >Java Resources
   >Libraries
     >JRE System Library
     >Maven dependencies
        >smallProj1.jar
        >smallProj2.jar
```

The thing is I do not have the all code for `smallProj1` and `smallProj2` and whenever add them to my workspace Eclipse overrides the maven dependencies and simply calls the two projects instead the jar files from my local maven repository and then I have all over the code those red underlines. Project properties in Eclipse looks as following after I add them to my workspace:

```
>Master project
>smallProj1
>smallProj2
  >Java Resources
   >Libraries
     >JRE System Library
     >Maven dependencies
        >smallProj1   (not jar anymore - folder)
        >smallProj2   (not jar anymore - folder)
```

Since I also want to have a look to `smallProj1` and `smallProj2` code while I am coding, I want to keep them both in my workspace. But I want my `Master project` to use the jar files that I provided, not the small projects in the workspace.

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1):

You could right click on a project and set "Maven" -> "Disable Workspace Resolution". This will let Maven find the dependencies from Maven and not within the workspace. I don't think it is possible to do this on a dependency basis.

But I think in your case it would be better to fix the broken smallProjX in your workspace (as they exactly contain the code you need), so that the master project could be build correctly.

Comment: yes I have been looking for disable workspace resolution thing - mostly I use netbeans. but I have a small question, but in that case F3 won't launch smallProjX  or? It launches directly jar files again...

Comment: @anvarik Yes, but you can simple add your projects as source. The editor should offer you an "Attach Source" button. There you can select a workspace project (or whatever you want).